Both multiple row selection and row view detail in aurelia slickgrid
Here is my grid defination and column definition.
defineGrid(): void {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        id: 'state',
        name: 'STATUS',
        field: 'state',
        sortable: true,
        type: FieldType.string,
        width: 50,
        filterable: true,
        cssClass: 'align-middle'
      },
      {
        id: 'customerName',
        name: 'customer Name',
        field: 'customerName',
        sortable: true,
        type: FieldType.string,
        width: 100,
        filterable: true,
        cssClass: 'align-middle'
      }
    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      autoResize: {
        container: '#demo-container',
        rightPadding: 10
      },

      enableFiltering: true,
      enableAutoResize: true,
      enableRowDetailView: true,
      enableCellNavigation: true,
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,
      checkboxSelector: {
        // optionally change the column index position of the icon (defaults to 0)
        columnIndexPosition: 1,

        // you can toggle these 2 properties to show the "select all" checkbox in different location
        hideInFilterHeaderRow: false
        //hideInColumnTitleRow: true,
        //applySelectOnAllPages: true // when clicking "Select All", should we apply it to all pages (defaults to true)
      },
      enableRowSelection: true,
      rowSelectionOptions: {
        selectActiveRow: false
      },
      autoHeight: true,
      rowHeight: 58, // increase row height so that the custom elements fits in the cell,
      //alwaysShowVerticalScroll: false,
      datasetIdPropertyName: 'rowId', // optionally use a different "id"
      rowDetailView: {

        columnIndexPosition: 2,


        process: (item: any) => this.simulateServerAsyncCall(item),
        loadOnce: true,
        singleRowExpand: false,

        useRowClick: false, //true,

        panelRows: 9, //this.detailViewRowCount,

        // ViewModel Template to load when row detail data is ready
        viewModel: PLATFORM.moduleName('../hello-world/hello-world'),
        parent: this
      }
    };
  }

I can get the aurelia slickgrid table with multi selection row with checkbox or rowViewDetail but not both at the same time. Is there a limitation in aurelia slickgrid? "aurelia-slickgrid": "^6.6.5" with aurelia 1. I am trying to get both multiple row selection and rowDetailView.

I've created this SlickGrid (core) Example - 3 plugins a while ago, so you should be able to do the same in Aurelia-Slickgrid. Maybe take a look at the grid options on that example

const columnIndex = 0; // which column index position do we want to add the checkbox selector?     const checkboxSelectorPlugin = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({ cssClass: 'slick-cell-checkboxsel' });     this.columnDefinitions.splice(columnIndex, 0, checkboxSelectorPlugin.getColumnDefinition());     this.gridOptions.registerPlugin(checkboxSelectorPlugin); I get the constructor error for new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn. Also, this registerPlugin is available in aurelia slickgrid 6.6.6? I didn't find it in src code.

I think i understand the problem a bit better now, when both row expand and row selection is enabled, only one gets registered into the library and other misses out.

I also tried react slickgrid demo today and noticed that row detail view, example 19 is missing there.

When I mentioned the example above, I didn't meant to use exactly the same code, it won't work that way in my libs. You should let the lib  do the plugin registering by itself and simply use flags to enable wanted features which is different compared to the original SlickGrid. If you register yourself then the library becomes out of sync and might override your registering (which it seems to do on your side). As for Slickgrid-React, yes I know Row Detail doesn't exists, I'm not a React developer and won't spend time on this. Lastly, Stack Overflow shouldn't be used for chatting

I tried Row Selections and Row Detail View with Example 19 of Aurelia-Slickgrid and as far as I can see, it's working fine with the options shown below. There's nothing really special about the settings except that you need to make sure to disable useRowClick because enabling it would conflict with Row Selection, but that's about it, the other options are just regular options.
this.gridOptions = {
  enableRowDetailView: true,
  enableCheckboxSelector: true,
  enableRowSelection: true,
  rowSelectionOptions: {
    // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
    selectActiveRow: false
  },
  checkboxSelector: {
    hideInFilterHeaderRow: false,
    hideSelectAllCheckbox: true,
  },
  rowDetailView: {
    // make sure to disable single row click to avoid conflict with Row Selection
    useRowClick: false,

    //...
  }
};

and as you can see from the animated gif below, it all seems to be working fine with both plugins enabled... Update: actually, I'm not sure why Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to upload the animated gif today but you can visit this imgur website link for the animated gif
https://imgur.com/t3bsldS
I was thinking to modify the Example 19 and upload the change, but I have Cypress E2E tests that also include tests for useRowClick, so I don't want to remove these tests neither modify the example, but anyway the only settings I've changed are shown above.
Please note that this is tested against v8.x and not v6.x, but I don't see anything that really changed in Row Detail between these 2 versions, so I assume the same settings should still be valid in v6.x

hmm...strange, here is my app.ts file .https://pastebin.mozilla.org/PZnRQZAT , For some reason i do not see any selection. https://imgur.com/a/ev4wuUd. My app.html is same as example19.html and rest same. "aurelia-slickgrid": "^6.6.6"

Sorry for additional comment, here is my package.json if i am missing anything. https://pastebin.mozilla.org/j10rZLsT#L16

I tried the same thing in Angular-Slickgrid and it works too, I don't think there's any differences from 6.x to 8.x on the Row Detail feature but even if there are, I just don't support older versions (I have too many projects to support freely). Sorry, I don't think I can't help more than that. It was also mentioned not long ago that Aurelia 2 will be in RC soon (though soon seems quite long in the Aurelia world, so we'll have to wait and see)

I would simply suggest to clone the Aurelia-Slickgrid-Demos and try different settings in the demo, even if it's Aurelia 2, it's still a good thing to test with.
